# rake aborted! No such file or directory - ant -version

Tags: ruby, ant, rake, ruboto

I just did a completely new (clean) install of ruby, jruby, and ruboto on a new machine (OSX 10.9). I followed all of the instructions and everything was going great until I got to the 'rake' step of the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Creating-Your-First-Ruboto-Application).

When I run 'rake' in the auto-magically created 'quick_start' directory I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - ant -version
/Users/KC/quick_start/rakelib/ruboto.rake:12:in ``'
/Users/KC/quick_start/rakelib/ruboto.rake:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/KC/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/KC/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

-Other notes: ruboto setup returns "Ruboto setup is OK!"

Comment: Do you have ant installed?

Comment: In the ruboto setup it gives "APACHE ant" found. But when I execute 'ant -version' I get -bash: ant: command not found. So I'm not sure if it is installed or not . . .

Comment: Sounds like a potential path problem, but it's difficult to say.

Comment: I'm sorta new, so I'm not sure how to diagnose/treat a path problem :) If I understand you correctly, you're saying that 'ruboto setup' may have failed to add ant to my path. So is there a way that I can add it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of ruboto has a small problem with OSX and correctly detecting the ant installation. So, until that gets fixed it will say ant is found, when it actually isn't.

Ruboto people are aware and will have a fix very soon. Until then you can just use homebrew:

```
brew install ant
```